# I can't import font and anchor. I updated python, but it's still not working. It's not my main app, but it's example

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-button

## Can't import alot of stuff from tkinter, like Font and anchor

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter
win= Tk()
win.geometry("300x550+970+45")
win.title("Gui")
l= Label(text="Save File").pack()
btn= ttk.Button(text= "Save",font('Arial',21)) # can't import font, I changed to font.Font and still not working
btn.pack(pady=10)
f= ttk.Frame(win,width=200,height=200).place(x=50,y=275)
f_canvas = Canvas(f,background='red',width=200,height=200)
f_canvas.create_image(0,0,anchor=tkinter.NW) # can't import anchor, even if I added a pic
f_canvas.place(x=50,y=275)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: post the error message @Omar Attia

Comment: You don't need to import anchor.  `anchor` is just a parameter.  Show us the traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
Learning/Gui/qr_code.py
  File "d:\Python\Learning\Gui\qr_code.py", line 72
    btn1 = ttk.Button(text="Clear",width=40,command=clear,font('bold',21))
@DanielleM.

Comment: Visual Studio Code considers `anchor` as a variable. there is in a complete menu `_ANCHOR`  and still confuse. I don't know how it works. @TimRoberts

Comment: Remove this anchor=tkinter.NW

Comment: Actually, it has no effect. So it's showing an error because `anchor` that I can't use it. @toyotaSupra

Comment: `font('Arial',21)` should be `font=('Arial',21)` - you want to provide a keyword parameter, not call a function.

Answer (score 0):

i tkink the error is caused by `tkk`, when i turn `btn= ttk.Button(text= "Save",font('Arial',21))` to `btn = Button(text="Save", font=('Arial', 21))` There is no error any more and the font is working at any time.You also don't need to `import font`.it's unneccessnary, it's already in tkinter.

here is the code without error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

win = Tk()
win.geometry("300x550+970+45")
win.title("Gui")
l = Label(text="Save File").pack()
btn = Button(text="Save", font=('Arial', 21))
btn.pack(pady=10)
f = ttk.Frame(win, width=200, height=200).place(x=50, y=275)
f_canvas = Canvas(f, background='red', width=200, height=200)
f_canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=tkinter.NW)  # can't import anchor, even if I added a pic
f_canvas.place(x=50, y=275)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It worked with that simple code, but it's not working on my app. :( @Danhui Xu

Comment: Maybe you should not use ttk and just use normal tkinter, maybe this will can fix problems.

Comment: By the way, font('Arial',21) should be font=('Arial',21)

Comment: I think `import tkinter` and `fom tkinter import *` is unnesseccary to do this two thing at the same time. and `tkinter.NW` cn just be `NW` without imoprt tkinter

Comment: Yeah, I add an equal sign, but it is still not working. I imported tkinter in two ways because I was trying to figure out the problem is it in importing or something else. Actually, I accessed tkinter module to look if there's font in button option or not. I found there's no font option there. @Danhui Xu

Comment: emmm..... i think the problem is not caused importing because `import tkinter` and `from tkinter import*` have the same effect.May be  the error is caused by ttk?

Comment: And L've check that tkinter's button has font option,i think maybe can fix your error.

Comment: Alright, Thank You.@ Danhui Xu

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Re-wrote script and add image and `tk.Photoimage`.

> I can't import font and anchor. I updated python, but it's still not
> working

I commented out the `import font` and `from tkinter import`. Actually, you don't need both.

Use `import tkinter as tk` then `tk` prefix.

Understanding how to to use `ttk.Style()`. For instance, `ttk.Button(win, ...,style='Heading.TButton')` #Heading.Tx .... x denote widget.

- In line 7, add `style = ttk.Style()`
- In line 9, add `style.configure('Heading.TButton', font=('Arial', 21))`
- In line 12, remove  keyword `font=('Arial',21)`
- In line 18, add `tk.Photoimage`.
- In line 19, add `x`, `y` coordinate of `create_image`.

Here is re-wrote for `ttk`:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

win= tk.Tk()
win.geometry("300x550+970+45")
win.title("Gui")
style = ttk.Style()

style.configure("Font.TButton", font=('Arial','21'))

l = tk.Label(win, text="Save File").pack()
btn = ttk.Button(text="Save", style="Font.TButton") #<== add style
btn.pack(pady=10)

f = ttk.Frame(win,width=200,height=200).place(x=50,y=275)
f_canvas = tk.Canvas(f,background='red',width=200,height=200)

img = tk.PhotoImage(file='p1.png') #<== add image
f_canvas.create_image(0, 10, image=img,anchor=tk.NW) #<== x, y coordinate
f_canvas.place(x=50,y=275)

win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot for `ttk` font and image:

[image]

Comment: Although There's no error, there's no effect on the font. Even in your screenshot.

Comment: Python 3.11.0rc1. Didn't you copied and pasted it?